# How to save a variable's number after changing it

Tags: php

I'm trying to save a variable's number after changing it, here is my code:

```
while($user_choice = fgets(STDIN)) {
    $nbrMatches = -15;

    $one = -1;
    $two = -2;
    $three = -3;

    if ($user_choice == 1) {
        echo $one - $nbrMatches . PHP_EOL;
        echo $nbrMatches . " remaining." . PHP_EOL;
    }

    else if ($user_choice == 2) {
        echo $two - $nbrMatches . PHP_EOL;
        echo $nbrMatches . " remaining." . PHP_EOL;
    }

    else if ($user_choice == 3) {
        echo $three - $nbrMatches . PHP_EOL;
        echo $nbrMatches . " remaining." . PHP_EOL;
    }   
}
```

The code above, doesn't save the variable's number, it just outputs the math. I would like to save it everytime $user_choice substract a number, it display as such:

```
Margaret@PC $ 1
1
14 remaining.
Margaret@PC $ 3
3
11 remaining.
```

It displays this instead:

```
Margaret@PC $ 1
1
14 remaining.
Margaret@PC $ 3
3
12 remaining.
```

Comment: @Loek: How is it? Please explain

Comment: `$one = -1;`, you save it right there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume when you say "save", you just mean to persist for the duration of the loop. Your current problem is that you are re-assigning `15` to the `$nbrMatches` variable at the start of each loop, which effectively resets it every time.

The solution here is to define `$nbrMatches` before the `while` loop, and then update it with each choice.

Something like this:

```
$nbrMatches = 15;

while($user_choice = fgets(STDIN)) {
    $one = 1;
    $two = 2;
    $three = 3;

    if ($user_choice == 1) {
        $nbrMatches -= $one;
        echo $one . PHP_EOL;
        echo $nbrMatches . " remaining." . PHP_EOL;
    }

    else if ($user_choice == 2) {
        $nbrMatches -= $two;
        echo $two . PHP_EOL;
        echo $nbrMatches . " remaining." . PHP_EOL;
    }

    else if ($user_choice == 3) {
        $nbrMatches -= $three;
        echo $three . PHP_EOL;
        echo $nbrMatches . " remaining." . PHP_EOL;
    }   
}
```

---

Of course, you could just use the user input directly and not have all those variables. For example:

```
$nbrMatches = 15;

while($user_choice = fgets(STDIN)) {
    $nbrMatches -= $user_choice;
    echo $user_choice . PHP_EOL;
    echo $nbrMatches . " remaining." . PHP_EOL;
}
```